# How to upload a file using express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, file-upload, express-session

I have an application in express, I need to upload a file, I am currently using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload), in the tests I did I had no problems:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const resizeImg = require('resize-img');

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
  var d = new Date();
  var newName = d.getHours()+'-'+d.getMinutes()+'-'+d.getSeconds()+'.jpg';
  console.log(newName)
  var rImage = 'C:/Developer/node/express-fileuploadWebix/public/images/'+newName;
  sampleFile.mv(rImage, function(err) {
    if (err)
    {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    resizeImg(fs.readFileSync(rImage), {width: 130, height: 180}).then(buf => {
      fs.writeFileSync(rImage, buf);
    });
    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
```

req.files.sampleFile has data!

But when I add [express-session](https://ewiggin.gitbooks.io/expressjs-middleware/content/express-session.html) to my app.js. Change the req and req.files no longer exists

Comment: Do you have `app.use(fileUpload());` in your code to actually install the fileupload code as middleware?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I added that, the problem is solved. Please include your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually run the `fileUpload` middleware, you need to add this line of code before your request handlers:

```
app.use(fileUpload());
```